# SQL Server: Listing Differences Between Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, report, relational-database

There are a few similar threads over the years regarding this but I haven't found or been able to do what I'm seeking.

I currently have two tables that have the same schema that I produce through a script. For name's sake, one is "results_prior" and the other is "results_current". This new query will ideally run once a month and find if there were any differences. Example:

TABLE: results_prior

```
----------------------------------------
| ID | ENVIRONMENT | EDITION | CONTACT |
----------------------------------------
| 03 | Development | 2008    | Bob     |
----------------------------------------
| 05 | Production  | 2012    | Phil    |
----------------------------------------
| 09 | Development | 2008    | Erik    |
----------------------------------------
| 13 | Production  | 2012    | Ashley  |
----------------------------------------
| 22 | Production  | 2012    | Erik    |
----------------------------------------
```

TABLE: results_current

```
----------------------------------------
| ID | ENVIRONMENT | EDITION | CONTACT |
----------------------------------------
| 03 | Development | 2008    | Bob     |
----------------------------------------
| 05 | Production  | 2012    | Phil    |
----------------------------------------
| 22 | Production  | 2012    | Erik    |
----------------------------------------
```

When the two are compared, the result should be:

```
----------------------------------------
| ID | ENVIRONMENT | EDITION | CONTACT |
----------------------------------------
| 09 | Development | 2008    | Erik    |
----------------------------------------
| 13 | Production  | 2012    | Ashley  |
----------------------------------------
```

Since 09 and 13 were in results_current. Likewise, and this is perhaps the tricky part, is having the same be done if results_current has more results than results_prior. So, vice-versa.

Sorry I have no example code to go off of. I have been goofing with UNION, JOINs, and EXCEPTs the last few hours and I feel like my logic (again, in SQL Server) is just not making any sense. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try something roughly similar to this:

```
SELECT ID, ENVIRONMENT, EDITION, CONTACT FROM RESULTS_PRIOR
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM RESULTS_CURRENT)
UNION
SELECT ID, ENVIRONMENT, EDITION, CONTACT FROM RESULTS_CURRENT
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM RESULTS_PRIOR)
```

Comment: I would do something similar, but I would substitute "NOT EXISTS" for the "NOT IN" clause.  NOT EXISTS works like a cut operator so at the first success, it will stop and not evaluate any more rows for that context.

Comment: Great replies to my question. However this is the one that gives me the results without having to jump through many hoops. I also replaced all the columns with * and managed to get the same result. Which may be beneficial in case every columns/fields are added down the road.

Answer (score 3):

This can be treated as the result set of `A-B union B-A`. I assume all the columns are the same in both the tables.Hence the `*` in `select`.

```
(select * from results_prior 
except
select * from results_current)
union all
(select * from results_current 
except
select * from results_prior)
```